# In html tag words are breaking

Tags: html, css

I want to preserve my paragraphs so I put that code in `pre` tag but after that my words are breaking. Is there any solution for this problem. I don't want to break my words, I also provided the `div` width. Below is my code :

```
<li class="list-group-item" ng-repeat = "answer in answers">

                    <span class="label label-default label-pill pull-xs-right " style="float: right">{{answer.UserID}}</span><br>
                    <pre style="font-family: helvetica;font-size: 14px;display: block;line-height: 20px;text-align: left "> {{answer.AnswerStr }} </pre>

            </li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check Chris Coyier's blog post: [Make "Pre" Text Wrap](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/make-pre-text-wrap/)

In short, add this to your CSS file:

```
/* Browser specific (not valid) styles to make preformatted text wrap */        

pre {
 white-space: pre-wrap;       /* css-3 */
 white-space: -moz-pre-wrap;  /* Mozilla, since 1999 */
 white-space: -pre-wrap;      /* Opera 4-6 */
 white-space: -o-pre-wrap;    /* Opera 7 */
 word-wrap: break-word;       /* Internet Explorer 5.5+ */
}
```

Comment: @avi What browsers do you use for testing? 
Also, check the comments from the blog post I linked above. There are other solutions and tweaks posted there, you might find one that suits your scenario.

Comment: @avi Check these 2 issues posted on the Chromium open source project: 
https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=4524 and https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=373502. You should find a solution there.